# How to save generated chart in media folder

Tags: python, django

I'm trying to store a simple sine graph generated within django itself and saving it in the media folder as static media to be served.

Here's my views.py that generates the graph but does not save it:

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from numpy import arange, sin, pi, radians
from matplotlib import pylab
from pylab import *
import PIL
import PIL.Image
import StringIO
from django.http import HttpResponse

def graph(request):
    if request.POST.get("choice") == "True":
        x = arange(0.0,1.0,0.01)
        y = sin(2*pi*x)
        plt.plot(x,y)

        buffer = StringIO.StringIO()
        canvas = pylab.get_current_fig_manager().canvas
        canvas.draw()
        graphIMG = PIL.Image.fromstring("RGB", canvas.get_width_height(), canvas.tostring_rgb())
        graphIMG.save(buffer,"PNG")
        pylab.close()

        return HttpResponse(buffer.getvalue(), content_type="image/png")

    else :
        error_message='Please select an option'
        return render(request, 'graph/graph.html', {'error_message': error_message})
```

Code was modified from a tutorial from sentdex's youtube tutorial:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=zxbCkftGyds&list=PLQVvvaa0QuDcTDEowl-b5nQlaDaD82r_s&index=15

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Save the image into the `MEDIA_ROOT` and return redirect to it:

```
import os
from django.conf import settings
from django.shortcuts import redirect

file_name = 'graph.png'
full_path = os.path.join(settings.MEDIA_ROOT, file_name)
with open(full_path, 'w') as f:
    f.write(buffer.getvalue())
return redirect(settings.MEDIA_URL + file_name)
```

Comment: Thanks. With a little modification to the saved path I was able to retrieve it.